# npm install update git submodule

Tags: node.js, git, npm, git-submodules

I have a Node JS lib with git submodule.
When I clone the git repository of my lib, I had to do `submodule update --init --recursive` something like this to pull the actual stuff from the submodule. 
After I released the lib and I did npm install my-lib and noticed it's not pulling the git submodule. How do I configure it so it pulls the git submodule? is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, as the submodule is, outside of git, just a simple file.

What you can do, however, is using the submodule only in development, compile your library and publish the compiled version in a `dist/` folder inside the package.

Then just point `main` in the `package.json` to the compiled library script and you can include it in your other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there's not git environment that's installed with npm i, but you could be explicit and in the scripts entry of package.json, add:

```
 "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "git init && git submodule add -f YOUR_REPO_URL LOCAL_PATH"
  }
```

Edit: That's however not the best option, because you won't be install to re-install your package. Prefer a simple git clone.